# Problems with Rounding Floats in Python

Tags: python, numpy, types, floating-point, rounding

I'm having a problem with np.round, np.around where it is not rounding properly.  I can't include code, because when I do it manually set the value (as opposed to use the my data), the return works, but here is the output:

```
In [177]: a
Out[177]: 0.0099999998

In [178]: np.round(a,2)
Out[178]: 0.0099999998


In [179]: np.round(a,1)
Out[179]: 0.0
```

What am I missing? The dtype of a is float32, do I need to change this?

Comment: Here. read all [that](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf)

Comment: What is your expected output? Maybe have a look at python's [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) type if you really must have an "exact" value.

Answer (score 6):

Try creating `np.float32(0.01)` and you will see your answer.  You are getting the precision you can already.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = 0.01
>>> epsilon = 0.01 - np.float32(0.01)
>>> for n in np.arange(x - 10*epsilon, x + 10*epsilon, epsilon):
...     print(repr(np.float32(n)))
...     
0.0099999979
0.0099999979
0.0099999979
0.0099999988
0.0099999988
0.0099999988
0.0099999988
0.0099999998
0.0099999998
0.0099999998
0.0099999998
0.0099999998
0.010000001
0.010000001
0.010000001
0.010000001
0.010000002
0.010000002
0.010000002
0.010000002
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but is there a different type I can change it to in order to avert this problem?

Comment: yes, for example `np.float64` .. but note that it doesn't avert the "problem", it only makes the error smaller.

Comment: classic leaky abstraction (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html). Welcome to floats.

Comment: Sorry, the "problem" that I'm having is that when I'm rounding the value, it does not round.  numpy.round(.0099999999, decimals=2) is still returning .0099999999999.  Thoughts?

Comment: @mike it depends what you want to use the rounded number for.  with `x = numpy.round(0.0099999999, decimals=2)` use `float(x)` to convert to 64-bit precision, or `'{0}'.format(x, precision=2)` if you need to write the number to two decimal places.

Comment: The issue is fundamental with floats and the float size will stay the same regardless as long as it stays a 32 or 64-bit float. What you want is to represent it differently, so just print it with string formatting ('0.3%f' %myfloat, '{:.3f}'.format(myfloat) ), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Note there seems to be an issue with python's `round` function and `numpy.float64` types. See example below:

```
In [88]: round(np.float64(16.259766999999947), 4)
Out[88]: 16.259799999999998
```

The only way I could fix this is to convert the `numpy.float64` to a float before using the round function as below:

```
In [89]: round(float(np.float64(16.259766999999947)), 4)
Out[89]: 16.2598
```

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work for me. If `x = 5672.1001`, then `np.round(float(np.float64(x)),1)` yields `5672.1000000000004`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work for me in cases the number is python's float or np.float64.

once I change the number to np.float32(), it works!

`type(85.10000000000001), np.round(85.10000000000001,decimals=2), np.round(np.float32(85.10000000000001),decimals=2)`

Results:
(float, 85.10000000000001, 85.1)